# If record exists fetch the existing column , compare it and then do an update Or else just insert new record

Tags: mysql

If the record doesn't exist , i need to insert a new  record , but if it exists then 
i need to select a particular column value from that row and do an update based on it .

I have managed to write down below query , which does insert / Update using duplicate on update

```
insert into securities(symbol, buyerquan, sellerquan , totaltradedquan) values('BANKBARODA', 73, 0, 4290270) on duplicate key update  buyerquan=buyerquan+VALUES(buyerquan),sellerquan=sellerquan+VALUES(sellerquan),totaltradedquan=totaltradedquan+VALUES(totaltradedquan)
```

This is my sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaf91/5

My requirement is

If the record exists , how can i fetch the existing column , compare it and then do an update ??

Do we need to write an another SQL query for fetching  existing column value ??

If record exists fetch the existing column , compare it and then do an update Or else just insert new record

Can we do all this in same query ??

Can anybody please help me .

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has a shortcut for that, it's called "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: But how can i fetch the existing column value with it??

Comment: This is appropriate for a comment but not for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague.  For instance, you don't specify what columns are used to define a duplicate.  Based on your query, I am guessing that you mean `symbol`.

Your query is:

```
insert into securities(symbol, buyerquan, sellerquan , totaltradedquan)
    values('BANKBARODA', 73, 0, 4290270)
    on duplicate key update buyerquan = buyerquan+VALUES(buyerquan), 
                            sellerquan = sellerquan + VALUES(sellerquan), 
                            totaltradedquan = totaltradedquan + VALUES(totaltradedquan);
```

This seems to be the right syntax (which for most people that is the hard part of the question).  The only thing that is missing is the specification of uniqueness:

```
create unique index securities_symbol on securities(symbol);
```

You can also specify this condition in the `create table` statement, using the `unique` keyword.

Comment: sorry for the imcomplete question , Yes correct , symbol is the primary key .